# Best way to get data from Rails 3 to Kendo UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, backbone.js, kendo-ui

What is the best way to get data from Rails 3 to some of Kendo UI's data intensive widgets (mostly grid and graphs)?

Lets say I have a Rails model which has data I want to show in Kendo's grid.  I imagine I will be passing that data via json.  But there seems to be many approaches to passing json data (gon, backbone.js,etc).  There is also the rails api approach (but I need the full rails for the other pages).

I was about to sit down and learn backbone.js.  Is this a good approach?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create an action that will serve your data as [JSON](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data). You do not need to use other JavaScript libraries. Take a look at this [project](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-rails), I think you might find it useful.